# Чи є відповідник для англійського "legalese" або російського "канцелярит"?

Tags: одним-словом

У різних мовах є назва особливого "жанру" лексики, пов'язаного із діяльністю бюрократичних, юридичних, офіційних структур. Англійською це <s>"[legalese](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/legalese?s=t)" (мова у якій високий відсоток юридичної термінології)</s>, "[officialese](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/officialese?s=t)" (офіційний стиль який тяжіє до довгих слів та багатословних конструкцій, які важко зрозуміти), російською його назвали "[канцелярит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82)" (назва, схожа на назву хвороби або мінералу).

Дивлячись на фразу, що була створена чиновниками одразу видно її "стабільність" — відсутність дієслів і намагання замінити їх іменниками, наприклад:

> Проводити заходи зі студентами щодо гідного ставлення до навчання, підвищення якості успішності та необхідності дотримання повсякчасно етичних норм поведінки.

Чи є якесь українське слово для цього офіційно-бюрократичного діалекту української мови?

Comment: Де-факто з 1975 використовується «канцелярит» ([Google Books](//www.google.com/search?q=канцелярит&num=100&lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks), [лейпцизький корпус](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=канцелярит)) — навіть у книжках, хоча часто в лапках (але не завжди).

Comment: Шоб там не було де-факто треба де-юре створити український новотвір заснований на питомо українському корені слова

Comment: @piznajko, створіть :).

Comment: @piznajko, до речі, якщо Ви писали це мені — то варто вказувати адресата через @ (он як я Вас). Інакше сповіщення про коментар отримує лише Artemix. Хоча якщо Ви писали це загалом усім — то без питань.

Comment: @Sasha, я хоч і не @piznajko, та спробую. Якщо йти шляхом утворення нового слова,  то найперше, що спадає на думку як відповідник до російського ***`канцелярит`*** (англійське  - ***`officialese`***) - ***`КАНЦЕЛЯРИСТИКА`***, адже: 1) одним словом, 2) співзвучне із *публіцистикою*, *белетристикою*, *журналістикою* тощо, тобто може стосуватися стилю загалом, а не його окремих складових, на противагу ***`канцеляризму`***. От з відповідником до англійського ***`legalese`*** за цим же алгоритмом дещо складніше: нічого путнього до голови не йде наразі. Детальніше - у відповіді нижче.

Answer (score 3):

Чесно кажучи, із запитання не зовсім зрозуміло, автор шукає відповідник англійському ***`legalese`*** чи російському ***`канцелярит`***.

Справа в тому, що в англійській мові є два окремих слова (даруйте за посилання на російський ресурс multitran.ru):

[***`legalese`***](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=legalese) - (*рос*.) юридический жаргон/стиль/терминология

і

[***`officialese`***](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=officialese&l1=1) - (*рос*.) канцелярский стиль, бюрократический жаргон, канцелярит, канцеляризм, канцелярщина, суконный язык.

Якщо орієнтуватись на СУМ, а також на те, що автор запитання шукає саме визначення особливого жанру/стилю, то, на мою думку, найкращим відповідником для ***`officialese`*** є

> [***`Суконна мова`***](http://sum.in.ua/s/sukonnyj), ***`суконний стиль`*** - **про важку або грубу мову, бідний стиль.** *Суконна
>   перекладацька мова справді-таки непридатна для писання оригінальних
>   творів* (Олексій Кундзіч, Діези.., 1956, 53),

а не [***`канцеляризм`***](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanceljaryzm), який позначає окреме "слово або зворот, притаманні стилю ділових паперів, документів", тобто складову стилю, а не власне стиль,

і не [***`канцелярщина`***](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanceljarshhyna), що більше стосується роботи або підходу до роботи, а не стилю мови.

Приклади вживання сталого вислову ***`суконна мова`***:

[1](https://bukvoid.com.ua/library/valentin_badrak/ofitserskiy_gambit_urivok_iz_romanu/3.html) *Суконна мова генерала Лимаревского ще якийсь час звучала в кімнаті. Але все сказане опісля було вже не важливо для полковника військової розвідки Олексія Сергійовича Артеменка* (Валентин Бадрак, Офіцерський гамбіт).

[2](http://ua.telekritika.ua/dusia-archive/12927/Alla_Kovtun___Z_odnogo_boku_-_potrebi_gazeti__z_%D1%96nshogo_-_zhiv%D1%96_ljudi) *Головною ж проблемою було те, що на шпальтах панувала суконна бюрократична мова, і більшість «місцевих» свято вірили в те, що урядова газета такою і має бути* (Інтерв'ю головного редактора «Урядового кур''єру» Алли Ковтун)

**UPD.** Якщо йти шляхом утворення нового слова,  то найперше, що спадає на думку як відповідник до російського ***`канцелярит`*** (англійське  - ***`officialese`***) - ***`КАНЦЕЛЯРИСТИКА`***, адже: 1) одним словом, 2) співзвучне із *публіцистикою*, *белетристикою* тощо, тобто може стосуватися стилю загалом, а не його окремих складових, на противагу ***`канцеляризму`***.

Знайшла навіть приклад вживання у статті Ворона О. П., кандидата історичних наук, старшого викладача кафедри філософії та економічної теорії Рівненського державного гуманітарного університету [ПРОФЕСІЙНА РЕЛІГІЙНА ОСВІТА РИМО-КАТОЛИЦЬКОЇ ЦЕРКВИ В УМОВАХ РОЗБУДОВИ УКРАЇНИ ЯК НЕЗАЛЕЖНОЇ ДЕРЖАВИ](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjly5iDvoXUAhVIECwKHafUAFwQFghWMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Firbis-nbuv.gov.ua%2Fcgi-bin%2Firbis_nbuv%2Fcgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF%2FNznuoairD2009_2010_2_8.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFc78w8DuZcHkhXHwrIq99a86bNpA&sig2=EnI3Y4p9wzxo-4yBHg_vQA), хоча в словниках не зустрічалось.

> Вивчається також психологія (загальна, пасторальна та психологія
>   розвитку), педагогіка і дидактика, патрологія, гомілетика, історія
>   церкви, екуменізм, інформатика, ***канцеляристика***.

От з відповідником до англійського ***`legalese`*** за цим же алгоритмом дещо складніше: нічого путнього до голови не йде наразі, окрім ***`юриспрудистики`***, але воно якесь надто кострубате.

Comment: Сумніваюсь, що в РКЦ є предмет з вивчання канцелярського стилю мови.

Comment: @Yola, я навела посилання на статтю. Чи є предмет, чи не має - питання до автора статті, напевно.

Comment: Я мав на увазі, що автор під цим словом розумів інше.

Comment: @Yola, Розширена цитата: "Особлива увага, поряд із богословськими науками, приділяється філософським дисциплінам. ... Так, студентами вивчаються філософія природи, методологія, теорія пізнання, вступ до філософії, філософська антропологія, філософія релігії, історія філософії, метафізика, теодицея. Вивчається також психологія (загальна, пасторальна та психологія розвитку), педагогіка і дидактика, патрологія, гомілетика, історія церкви, екуменізм, інформатика, канцеляристика."

Comment: Я дивився документ, і у мене не склалось враження, що вони вивчають канцелярський стиль мови. Мабуть, вони ви вивчають ділову мову чи щось таке.

Comment: @Yola, так канцелярський (як і юридичний) стилі це, мабуть, і є підвиди мови ділової. Принаймні, я так сприймаю.

Comment: @Yola [Звідси](http://dilomova.org.ua/?p=53): "В офіційно-діловому мовному стилі виділяють такі підстилі:
1. Законодавчий-....
2.Дипломатичний-....
3.Юридичний -....
4.Адміністративно-канцелярський - використовуєть­ся в професійно-виробничій сфері, правових взаєминах і діловодстві у вигляді офіційної кореспонденції, дого­ворів, контрактів, заяв, автобіографій, доручень тощо." Цілком ймовірно, що вивчають. Чому ні?

Comment: @Yola, я думаю, вони взагалі мають під цим на увазі церковне діловодство (справочинство, документообіг) — а не якийсь стиль мовлення (тобто «канцеляристика» в тому контексті — ІМХО, дисципліна про формальне ведення церковних справ).

Comment: На справді питання відштовхувалося від "канцеляриту", напевно "legalese" справді має інше значення.

Answer (score 2):

Неодноразово чула і вживала слово *канцелярщина*, ось [тут](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanceljarshhyna) воно теж є.

Comment: Все-ж таки це більш загальне - "зайвий формалізм у роботі" або "канцелярська робота".

Comment: @Artemix, є ще [_канцеляризм_](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanceljaryzm), можливо воно краще описує?

Comment: Це вже краще, але про окремі типові для канцелярського стилю звороти. Хіба що можна про весь текст сказати "суцільний канцеляризм".

Comment: @Artemix, а мені здається, «канцелярщина» якраз краще пасує за «канцеляризм». Бо «канцеляризм» має нейтральне забарвлення (і, мені здається, воно було цілком очевидним для автора під час написання запитання; виглядає так, що автор шукає щось типу «канцеляризму», але з негативним відтінком; бо інакше б він питав про відповідник російського «[канцеляризм](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Канцеляризмы)» (таке слово є і в рос. мові), а не про відповідник російського «[канцелярит](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Канцелярит)»). А в «канцелярщини» друге значення якраз «*надмірний* формалізм», тобто зневаж.-негат.

Comment: @Sasha Я теж згоден що канцелярщина звучить як треба, але у словнику інше значення. Можливо це слово і можна використовувати в потрібному смислі, але тоді треба було б навести існуючі приклади які це доводять.